# How to render the next view in a controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, capybara

My controller action does the following:

1. Saves a newly POSTed instance of a user
2. Sends an email to the new user
3. Redirects to the user's homepage

I'm doing some quick and dirty view tests, just in the controller test... not robust enough for me to want to separate out into view test.

The problem is that I can test #1 and #2, but not #3. In other words, here is my test code:

```
describe "create - with valid, new data" do
    it "creates a new signup" do
     expect{
       post :create, signup: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:signup)
     }.to change(Signup,:count).by(1)
    end

    it "redirect to form page" do
     post :create, signup: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:signup)
     response.should render_template "subscribe/notification_email"
    end

    it "redirect to form page" do
     post :create, signup: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:signup)
     response.should render_template "homepage"
    end
end
```

The first two tests are passing, the last is failing. Is there a way to tell the controller test to go to the next thing that is rendered? Or how else can I test this?

Comment: response.should redirect_to("homepage")

Comment: if you test the status code you would see that it is getting a 302 (resource temporarily relocated or some such) and technically speaking I believe the redirect status is accompanied by a sparse webpage that only contains an anchor tag with the link to the new resource location (in case your browser does not redirect automatically)... so it makes sense that it is failing on the should render_template "homepage" because it is actually rendering that redirect page

Comment: Ok so that worked, but then how can I test specific fields within the redirected page? I.e., my test code that's passing is now 1) `response.should render_template "subscribe/notification_email"` 2) `response.should redirect_to "homepage"` 3) I'd like to add this 3rd test that is `response.should have_field('Email')` to test for a field in the homepage, but it's not passing. Since it does pass where there's only a `redirect` and not both a `redirect` and a `render`, I suspect the Capybara is looking for the text in the rendered email template not the redirected homepage, how do I change this?